# Distinct from select statement with Left Joins

Tags: sql, database

How do i select a Distinct value from a select statement with LEFT JOINS?
The value I'm after is one of either s_id from trainingTbl or setName from setsTbl.

The full string is provided below.

```
Dim strQuery As String = 
  "SELECT * 
     FROM userAssessmentTbl 
     LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id 
     LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id
     LEFT JOIN outcomesTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.o_id = outcomesTbl.o_id 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
    ORDER BY t_date DESC "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for uniqueness

```
SELECT * 
FROM  userAssessmentTbl 
LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id 
LEFT JOIN outcomesTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.o_id = outcomesTbl.o_id 
WHERE UserId = @UserId 
GROUP BY trainingTbl.s_id
ORDER BY t_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT  trainingTbl.s_id  FROM  
userAssessmentTbl LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id 
LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id 
LEFT JOIN outcomesTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.o_id = outcomesTbl.o_id 
WHERE UserId = @UserId ORDER BY t_date DESC
```

or this (not sure what exactly you need)

```
SELECT DISTINCT  trainingTbl.s_id, setsTbl.setName  FROM  
userAssessmentTbl LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id 
LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id 
LEFT JOIN outcomesTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.o_id = outcomesTbl.o_id 
WHERE UserId = @UserId ORDER BY t_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place your problem is that you are using select * (A SQL antipattern and something that should NEVER appear in production code) and thus each record is unique so adding distinct or group by will not work.

It is not the left joins causing the proble, an inner join would have the same problem. The problem is that you have a one-to-many relationship between the tables and thus have multiple records when you join them. If you only want one record per id in the first table, then you must specify which record or individual data field in the other tables you want - either use aggregate functions to get the record you want to match or do some sort of filtering in the join to make sure you have a one-to-one relationship. Without knowing your data and your business rules, I cannot suggest what is best to  do.

Comment: I'm not actually after one record per ID from the first table but one record per ID from the setTbl table.

Comment: Yes and that is what you have to do in your code, specify which record of the several that you want.

Comment: There is no easy solution to this, you need to do the due diligence to find out the business rules  that allow you to end up with only one record. That can't be answered on the INternet.

Comment: I'm not actually after one record per ID from the first table (userAssessmentTbl) but one record per ID from the setTbl table. The setTbl table consists of, lets say 10 sets only and each one is individual. What I'm trying to do is display each record from the sets table only once and for the data in the relational tables to correspond. I thought that a may be able to do this with the SQL distinct function?

Comment: Your problem is that you have multiple rcords in the third table inthe joins then. You still need to findout how to limit it to one set of records. It is still a due diligence problem of dcorrectly defining your requirement. We cannot help you with that.